# Passing empty parameters to javascript function with Chrome

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, parameters

I have the following markup:

```
<a href="#" onclick="boom('fus', '', 'dah')">Pow</a>
```

And a JavaScript function:

```
function boom(first, second, third) {
    // Do bad stuff with parameters
}
```

In IE8, this works great. In Chrome, the onclick method doesn't even fire. Note the empty parameter in the markup. If that parameter was filled, Chrome won't have a problem with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try passing null instead of ''.

Comment: Thanks for the clean-up, David. :)

Comment: What's wrong with an empty string, Craig?

Comment: Really annoiyng, can you provide a jsfiddle? It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/AeLKJ/

Comment: jsFiddle seems to work perfectly fine in Chrome here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/THSKD/.  Either your question is not clear or there is something else going on that you have not disclosed.  It's perfectly OK to pass `''` for a function argument.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the parameters? And how do you know "the onclick method doesn't even fire"?

Comment: I see that it works fine in JSfiddle with Chrome. I'll look at my code again and see if anything is off.

Comment: I see your problem. Your second parameter should be 'ro'.

Comment: In Chromes debugger/element inspector, I can see that there's about 4 white space characters where ever I put an empty parameter. Removing that causes the link to work again. I contruct the link using javascript/jquery (it's not hard coded into the markup). I think i have a good example here: http://jsfiddle.net/THSKD/7/

Comment: The magic line in the working fiddle might be `window.boom = boom`. When I tried to set this up myself, I kept getting a reference error on the `boom` function. It seems it was necessary, for some reason, to assign that function to the window.

Answer (score 0):

Formal parameters only initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed.

so you should try this

```
<a href="#" onclick="boom('fus', undefined, 'dah')">Pow</a>
```